# Nativescript-Vue local image not showing up

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I'm new to nativescript-vue and trying to make use of the Image tag to show a local image SVG, the url is like this:

```
/app/assets/images/logo.svg
```

My folder structure

[image]

In my code I placed this, but sadly no image is shown:

```
<Image src="/app/assets/images/logo.svg" stretch="none" style="width:200; height:200;"></Image>
```

Comment: Does `<Image src="./app/assets/images/logo.svg" stretch="none" style="width:200; height:200;"></Image>` or `<Image src="./assets/images/logo.svg" stretch="none" style="width:200; height:200;"></Image>
`works?
`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to declare it using '~' to indicate a known root folder. Try this:
src='~/assets/images/logo.svg'